# Using dplyr and data.table with get() for reusibility and shiny - good practices in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Main question:
What's the best way to pass variables to dplyr and data.table -  when variables are not hard-coded but are acquired from user at run-time, as when entered from Shiny?

Example 1:

```
df <- mtcars
dt <- mtcars %>% as.data.table

input <- list(); input$newcol="rate"; input$numerator="cyl"; input$denominator="wt"

df <- df %>% mutate(get(input$newcol)=get(input$numerator)/get(input$denominator))
dt[ , ':='(get(input$newcol)=get(input$numerator)/get(input$denominator))]
```

Example 2: (The same as example 1 but referencing columns by number)

```
input$numerator=2; input$denominator="6"
```

Example 3 (The same as examples 1 and 2, but using array of variables ):

```
input$newcols=paste("rate_", 1:3); 
input$numerators=1:3 
# or input$numerators=c("cyl", "disp", "hp"); 
input$denominators=5:7
```

And tangent questions:
Q1: What is wrong in the example 1 above? (the error message is shown below)
`Error: unexpected '=' in "df %>% mutate(get(input$newcol)="`

Q2: Can/Should one use `as.name()` instead of `get()` ? When one should use the former, and when the latter?

PS:
I'm suprised this is not normally discussed anywhere in early stages of R learning books (including from Harley and Matt Doyle). If I would teach R, this would be the first skill I would teach  - how to write code that it is reusable with any variable (not with just hard-coded variable), like we teach C++ or Java.
Comment on this PS are also welcome.

Comment: Specifically regarding Shiny and dplyr, you may find [this chapter in Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html) useful.

Comment: You need to read about [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) (specifically [*"one or more user-supplied expressions"*](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#one-or-more-user-supplied-expressions)).

Comment: The same topic for `data.table` applies as well: https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html#programming-on-data-table-1

Comment: As to your PS, it's more of an opinion piece than a question on R, dplyr, or data.table. StackOverflow is not meant as a discussion forum, it is for concrete problems and solutions. Not only do I disagree with the premise (that the first think you teach about a programming language is *meta*-programming; perhaps I'm biased, the 10+ languages I've studied were never taught that way), it is more appropriate as a conversation over a PR you draft to improve their documentation with your own suggestions. I think it is off-topic here.

Comment: I suggest not to blame the teachers in case when a student does not understand the study materials. This gives you a false start...

Comment: Nevertheless, this will do the job (for data.table) `dt[, input[[1]] := get(input[[2]]) / get(input[[3]])]` or `dt[, input[["newcol"]] := get(input[["numerator"]]) / get(input[["denominator"]])]`